# Schengen Visa Audits

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, standard-visitor-visas, long-stay-visas

It's a very straightforward question:

Does anyone know whether embassies and consulates of Schengen Member States perform audits on visas they issued? Do they ever go through the applications in greater detail, or any sort of detail for that matter, after issuance?

This is out of sheer curiosity, I like to know the legal workings of things.

Comment: There is some checks. E.g. percentage of rejections (compared nearby countries and specific factors). Unexplained change on short period rise a red flag. The number of abuse is also controlled. Check of single application is difficult: officers are trained to "feel" if you tell the truth and your real plan, but nothing really objective (and verifiable), and it will hinder rejections. So as far I know, it is mostly about statistic (and some quality check).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi, that should be posted as an answer, not a comment. Please do so.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For example, a decade ago there was a big corruption investigation in the German visa section in Kiew.

[German language news report](https://www.fr.de/politik/visa-gegen-bargeld-11468733.html).

Comment: Switzerland had a similar issue (I think Pakistan, or nearby *-stan* country)